# What is the closest font used in this logo?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: Tracer Logo]
I need to find the name of the font used in this logo. Online tools can't identify it because of the design.

Comment: It may be safe to assume this isn't a font. Rather, it's been modified for the purpose of the logo (like most logos). Personally, if this is an effect I was after, I would try and make a similar version from scratch. I encourage you to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try these, they are free:

[image]

No exact match, but you can play a little with stroke width and its placement, if the wanted thing was to recreate the logo. For it you must in any case build the design by modifying the outlined letters,  so you can as well draw the logo from scratch having a locked image as your model.

That should be moderately easy, if using illustrator or Inkscape is familiar. Drawing the lines and curves over your image takes no more than a couple of minutes per letter:

[image]

A hint: draw long horizontal lines at first and split them to get absolutely consistent height. Lock them as soon as possible. You can also insert quides.